# How can I run script after deploy to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I have an application in node.js which depends on env variables. I made some changes in code and now one of this vars should be changed after deploy. I don't want to do this manually. What is the best practise to do this automatically.

I guess that running some script after deploy could be solution, but I want to run this script only once (with this one particular change).

My only idea is that I should have script that will be checking (after each deploy) some directory if there is another script to run and then run it and remove it. But how can I achieve that?

Comment: [this link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#cli-commands-for-dyno-management) may be helpful. basically you run `heroku run bash -a <appname>` to login to heroku

Answer (score 0):

The best way to approach this is to use the [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/) to set your environment variables [as described here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars):

```
heroku config:set GITHUB_USERNAME=joesmith
```

You can then refer to these variables in your Node.js application by using the following syntax:

```
var dbUsername = process.env.DB_USERNAME;
```

Assuming you set a DB_USERNAME variable like this:

```
heroku config:set DB_USERNAME=myAppUserName
```

I like to ensure there's a fallback if the environment variable is not set, you can achieve that like this:

```
var dbUsername = process.env.DB_USERNAME || 'fallbackUsername';
// The string after || will be used if the process.env.DB_USERNAME variable is undefined (not set)
```

Comment: Ok, but how can I run this: `heroku config:set GITHUB_USERNAME=joesmith` after pushing to heroku? Automatically and only once.

Comment: You need to do this from your local machine using the Heroku Toolbelt - once this is set it will remain for the entire lifecycle of your application.

Comment: Did this work for you? If so please be sure to set my answer as accepted :)

Comment: No, since it requires to run this command manually. I think that in my case expand/contract pattern will be better solution.

Comment: I disagree - surely once you've set it, you won't need to set it again?